# How to get specific columns in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I wanna select specific columns from table. Not all columns.

```
$this->userModel->where($where)->first();
```

I'm using this but it returns all data.

Comment: Do you know names of these columns? Syntax of `$this->userModel->where($where)` is weird for me. Would you like to use some separated method in model which will make a select for return?

Comment: do `print_r( $this->userModel->where($where)->first()` and show us what are you getting.

Comment: yes i know names of columns. how can i select like userid, username only

Comment: your question is not clear but for now, what I got is you can use `Where`.

Comment: i wanna select specific columns like we were did on Ci3 select('userid,username')

Comment: `$this->userModel` has inbuilt stuff like `$db->table('mytable');`?

Comment: Are you familiar with codeigniter 4? if yes i need this thing select userid,username from userid=5 in ci4 methods.

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data may help...

Comment: @dalelandry, CI3 has another syntax. There is case with CI4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CI4 query builder documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query) you can use **select()** in this way:

```
$db      = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table('mytablename');        // 'mytablename' is the name of your table

$builder->select('userid, username');       // names of your columns, single string, separated by a comma
$builder->where('userid', 5);                // where clause
$query = $builder->get();

return $query;
```

[where()](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query#looking-for-specific-data) could be possible to use in 4 ways, you can choose.

This stuff should be placed in Model file, method of which would return `$query` set of DB data.

Comment: This solve my problem thanks a lot for getting records i add this thing in code $query->getFirstRow($this->tempReturnType)

Comment: @user1951608, you're welcome! Now you have CI4 documentation) It's weird that CI3 and CI4 have different websites, I thought they'd updated CI3 website, but no, they've created separated website.

Comment: CI4 has improved a lot from CI3, and the CI3 userbase is higher as well, so separate website is better in my point of view.

Comment: $builder->select('userid','username'); did not work for me. It selected only userid.

In CI 4 docs, $builder->select() takes only the first parameter as a string of your column names. So it should be a string with comma separated values:
$builder->select('userid, username');

Answer (score 1):

(Tested under CI 4.2.7)

There is also a *select* method in the model, which accepts an array of columns:

```
$userModel->select(['id','name'])->where('id', 1)->first();
```